# selecting subset following two conditions

Tags: r, matrix

I've been struggling with a particular aspect of R which is selecting subset of my data that satisfy a few parameters. For example, let's say I have a matrice Y of sites and 5 species abundance :

```
 site    spc1        spc2         spc3          spc4         spc5 
 195     1            1            3            0            15
 196     3            15           4            0            18
 197     0            0            0            85            0
 198     2            1            3            0            85
 199     0            0            0            75            0
```

Let say that spc4 is problematic, that it wasn't identify correctly. I would like to take out from my matrice Y all the lines where the sum of the abundance of all the other spc is equal to 0 AND the abundance of spc4 is >0, and store the new matrice without all those lines in another matrice called Z. 
I've tried a few things but I don't seem to know how to substract those line of interest and create a new dataset. 
I am learning how to create function in the meantime and I'm investigating ways to create If function.

If anyone has any idea, I'd love to read it.

Thanks !

Comment: Is this a matrix or a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a matrix `mat`

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(mat)
spcs <- names(dat)[!names(dat) %in% c("site", "spc4")]
Z <- as.matrix(dat[!(spc4 > 0 & get(spcs) == 0)])

#      site spc1 spc2 spc3 spc4 spc5
# [1,]  195    1    1    3    0   15
# [2,]  196    3   15    4    0   18
# [3,]  198    2    1    3    0   85
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R...

```
Z <- subset(Y, !(rowSums(Y[, -1]) == Y[, "spc4"] & Y[, "spc4"] > 0))

Z
  site spc1 spc2 spc3 spc4 spc5
1  195    1    1    3    0   15
2  196    3   15    4    0   18
4  198    2    1    3    0   85
```

This should work whether Y is a matrix or a dataframe, but in the latter case you could replace `Y[,"spc4"]` with `Y$spc4`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a data frame, we can use `dplyr`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "site    spc1        spc2         spc3          spc4         spc5 
 195     1            1            3            0            15
                 196     3            15           4            0            18
                 197     0            0            0            85            0
                 198     2            1            3            0            85
                 199     0            0            0            75            0",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load packages
library(dplyr)

# Process data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  filter(!(spc4 != 0 & rowSums(dt %>% select(-site, -spc4)) == 0))
```

Comment: Some ambiguity in the question is causing us to get the same answer on the sample data, but different answer on a different case. Assume two new rows are added. `200    0    0    0    0    0` and `201    1    2    1    1    0`. Your code filters these out, but my answer keeps these. My understanding was to remove only those rows where spc4 > 0 AND all other rows are 0.

Comment: @EricWatt I agree with you. I have updated my code, which should result in the same output as your code now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers ! I'm going to try it out on my data in a minute. Your help is much appreciated.